# How to Auto Fill my current address to a search box

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic-view

Greeting, I'm new to IONIC and now i have met a problem. I'm trying to include a google map direction services in my application. The application now will jump to the location A once i input the address in the search box, but what i want is when i 1st open the app, search box A will automatically get my location address and fill the address in the textbox A.

TaxiServices.html

```
<div class="bar bar-header bar-dark item item-button-left">
  <!--<a class="button icon-left ion-chevron-left button-clear button-dark"  ng-click="st.link()">Home Page</a>-->
 <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="ts.link()">
<i class="icon ion-arrow-left-c"></i>
  </button>
  <h1 class="title">Taxi Services TEST</h1>
</div>
<ion-view ng-app="taxiservice" ng-controller="MapController">
  <ion-content class="has-footer has-header" scroll="false">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="titlebar">
        <div class="preorder">
      <!--http://jsfiddle.net/ucmL2/-->
      <ion-checkbox ng-model="ModelData.Animals">Pre-Order</ion-checkbox>
      <div class="form-group" ng-show="ModelData.Animals">
        <form action="action_page.php">
          Date & Time :
          <input type="datetime-local" class="datetime">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="places">
      <input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text"
             placeholder="Enter an origin location">

      <input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
             placeholder="Enter a destination location">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>

  <div class="fare has-footer">
    <h3>Estimated Fare: </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

taxiservice-ctrl.js

```
var map;
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
.module('taxiservice.ctrl', [])
.controller('TaxiServiceCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicPopup', '$timeout', '$rootScope', '$interval', '$window', '$ionicLoading',
  function ($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout,$rootScope,  $interval, $window, $ionicLoading) {
    //variables
    var self = this;
    self.link = link;


    function link() {
      $window.location.href = "../../js/ServiceMenu/index.html";
    }


    $scope.showPopup = function() {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Good News!',
        template: 'Yay! We have found you a driver!'
      });
      alertPopup.then(function(res) {
        $window.location.href = "../../js/TaxiFound/index.html";
      });
    };

  }])

.controller('MapController', function ($scope, $ionicLoading) {

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
    var origin_place_id = null;
    var destination_place_id = null;
    var travel_mode = google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeControl: false,
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 17
    });

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
      var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
        map: map,
        title: "My Location"

      });
    });

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var origin_input = document.getElementById('origin-input');
    var destination_input = document.getElementById('destination-input');


    var options = {
      types: ['geocode'],
      componentRestrictions: {country: 'my'}
    };

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(origin_input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destination_input);


    var origin_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(origin_input, options);
    origin_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    var destination_autocomplete =
      new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destination_input, options);
    destination_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
    // Autocomplete.


    function expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place) {
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);
      }
    }

    origin_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = origin_autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

      // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
      // the other place ID
      origin_place_id = place.place_id;
      route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
        directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    });

    destination_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = destination_autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

      // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
      // the other place ID
      destination_place_id = place.place_id;
      route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
        directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    });

    function route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
                   directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
      if (!origin_place_id || !destination_place_id) {
        return;
      }
      directionsService.route({
        origin: {'placeId': origin_place_id},
        destination: {'placeId': destination_place_id},
        travelMode: travel_mode
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
    }

  });

});
})();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *">
  <title></title>

  <link href="../../css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="../../lib/angular/angular.js"></script>

  <script src="../../lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="../../lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="../../lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="../../lib/ionic/js/ionic.js"></script>
  <script src="../../lib/ionic/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>
</head>
     <body ng-app="taxiservice">

<ion-nav-view>
</ion-nav-view>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&callback=&libraries=places&sensor=false">
</script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="map.js"></script>
    <script src="content/taxiservice-ctrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular
  .module('taxiservice', [
     'ionic',
     'taxiservice.ctrl'
  ])

        .run(function($ionicPlatform,$timeout) {
     $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar      above the keyboard
  // for form inputs)
  if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  }
  if(window.StatusBar) {
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
       }

     });
   })
   .config(function($ionicConfigProvider,$stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    templateUrl: 'content/TaxiService.html',
    controller:'TaxiServiceCtrl as ts'
  });

// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');

  });
```

I have struggled with this problem very long times, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Look the reverse geocoding example here. You can retrieve the address by using the position which you already have and then add the marker. https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/geocoder

Answer (score -1):

A good plugin i use on my app for fill Google Maps Autocomplete is

https://github.com/israelidanny/ion-google-place

Easy to install , reverse geocoding included , Great Template

the customization is easy

Good Luck